# Flex mobile: Zoom and scroll in bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, charts, scroll, zooming

I'm making a mobile application with a bargraphs in it. I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 and Flex SDK 4.6.0.

In my appication I'm using the builtin Bar Graph from Flash Builder. Is there a possibility to zoom and scroll with this chart. Remembder that it is a mobile app (iPad) so it needs to work with gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First](http://blog.ninjacaptain.com/2010/03/flex-chart-zoom-window/) and [sixth](http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/07/scrolling-and-zooming-chart-with-chartscroller/) result on google for flex chart zoom.

This does not show how to work with gestures in this case, but I haven't seen any charting engines for flex mobile that do, so you'd have to write your own I'm afraid.
But I don't see any reason why scrolling wouldn't work. Not sure about the pinch zoom though.
Don't expect butter smooth performance from the MX charts, though. On a mobile with large data sets they are slow as hell.

Comment: I tried the examples you mentioned already. The scrolling does work indeed on a mobile project, but the zooming doesn't. It's a begin but I was hoping for more.

Comment: As I said, I haven't seen any charting engines for flex that are mobile ready, or at least handle the bare minimum gestures, and trust me, I've searched for hours. There won't be a way around either making the MX charts work with a pinch zoom gesture (that should actually work, but mind the issue of dynamic registration), or writing your own mobile optimized charts from scratch.

Comment: Ok, thx for the info! I'll try to figure something out that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add the chart in a Group and add gestureZoom on the Group.

```
private function onGestureZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    if(canvas.scaleY.valueOf() >= 1)
    {
        canvas.scaleX *= event.scaleX;
        canvas.scaleY *= event.scaleY;
    }else
    {
        canvas.scaleX = 1;
        canvas.scaleY = 1;
    }
}

<s:Group id="canvas"  gestureZoom="onGestureZoom(event)" width="100%" height="100%">
   <!-- chart (set width and height to 100%)-->
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Not a bad start, but it always zooms to the top left.